# If RE languages are closed under intersection, why aren't CFLs?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

Since we can prove that Recursively Enumerable (RE) languages are closed under intersection, and that Context Free Languages (CFLs) are RE, why then are CFLs not closed under intersection?

Edit: This really was a stupid question if there ever was one. All CFLs are RE languages. But the RE languages being closed under intersection only means the intersection of two CFLs is RE.

Comment: The integers are closed under doubling, and primes are integers, so why is the set of primes not closed under doubling?

Comment: And actually the recursively enumerable languages are _not_ closed under complement. I suspect you're confusing that with _regular_ languages instead. (But context-free languages are in general not regular, so it still doesn't quite add up).

Comment: The confusion might be with the recursive languages rather than the regular ones, @HenningMakholm. In that case the inclusion is given.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Great example. That makes it clear, thanks!

Comment: I have made an important edit. I meant to say that REs are closed under intersection, but not CFLs.

Comment: The infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ also are not closed under intersection, while all subsets of  $\mathbb{N}$ are. The reason why RE are closed while CFLs are not is probably related to their respective computational models recognising them, Turing machines and non-deterministic pushdown automata.

Comment: For completeness, a classical counterexample (which hasn’t been mentioned yet) comes from strings of the form $a^k b^m c^n$.  It’s easy to see that “strings with an equal number of $a$ and $b$” and “strings with an equal number of $b$ and $c$” are both CFLs.  But their intersection is “strings with equal number of $a$, $b$ and $c$”, and that is not a CFL, by a textbook application of CFL pumping lemma.  Informally, a PDA lacks the ability to consume the same counter twice.

Comment: What about deleting your question, since you discovered it "really was a stupid question"?